# How can we know the usage of ram for eos?

Tags: ram, ram-allocation, ramcore

Is there exist an table which we can know how much ram we consumed?
Or is there exist an api can help for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Usage of RAM for an account:

  ```
  $ cleos get account <account_name>
  ```
- Maximum RAM of the network (`max_ram_size`):

  ```
  $ cleos get table eosio eosio global
  ```
- Unused RAM of the network:

  ```
  $ cleos get table eosio eosio rammarket
  ```